# Composable functions in Puppeteers page.Evaluate

Tags: puppeteer

I'm relatively new to puppeteer and I'm trying to understand the patterns that can be used to build more complex apis with it. I am building a cli where I am running a WebGL app in puppeteer which i call various functions in, and with my current implementation i have to copy and paste a lot of setup code.

Usually, in every cli command i have to setup pupeteer, setup the app and get access to its api object, and then run an arbitrary command on that api, and get the data back in node.

It looks something like this.

```
const {page, browser} = await createBrowser() // Here i setup the browser and add some script tags.

let data;
page.exposeFunction('extractData', (data) => {
   data = data;
})  

await page.evaluate(async (input) => {
// Setup work
const requestEvent = new CustomEvent('requestAppApi', {
    api: undefined;
})

window.dispatchEvent(requestEvent);
const api = requestEvent.detail.api;

// Then i call some arbitrary function, that will 
always return some data that gets extracted by the exposed function. 

const data = api.arbitraryFunction(input);
window.extractData(data)
}, input)
```

What i would like is to wrap all of the setup code in a function, so that i could call it and just specify what to do with the api object once i have it.

My initial idea was to have a function that will take a callback that has this api object as a parameter.

```
const { page, browser } = wait createBrowser();
page.exposeFunction(async (input) => 
    setupApiObject(((api) => 
        api.callSomeFunction(input)
    ), input)
```

However, this does not work. I understand that puppeteer requires any communication between the node context and the browser to be serialised as json, and obviously a function cant be. Whats tripping me up is that I'm not actually wanting to call these methods in the node context, just have a way to reuse them. The actual data transfer is already handled by page.exposeFunction.

How would a more experienced puppeteer dev accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question here, since i managed to figure out a way to do it. Basically, you can use `page.evaluate` to create a function on the window object that can later be reused.

So i did something like

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.useApiObject = function(callback: (api) => void){
    // Perform setup code
    callback()
  }
})
```

Meaning that later on i could use that method in the browser context and avoid redoing the setup code.

```
page.evaluate(() => {
  window.useApiObject((api) => {
      api.someMethod()
  })
})
```